# Bezier Path with dynamic change of width

Tags: ios, drawing, uibezierpath

I want to create bezier path with dynamically changing line's width. I need spending the same amount of color on each part of line. So, longer line should be thinner. And shorter line should be bold. Or, at least, line should change it's width from beginning to the end.
Any ideas how to achieve it?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate more and give images of above scenario to clearly understand above problem .

Answer (score 0):

the only way to achieve this is with multiple `UIBezierPath`s of different thickness and colour.