# CGContextStrokePath not working when zooming and drawing images

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, core-graphics, pinch

I'm drawing lines according to `touchesMoved:` method and normally it works fine. But when I zoom into the image and draw, the previously drawn lines are both displaced and keep getting more and more blurry, ultimately vanishing. I've tried using `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and simply increasing the `frame` of `myImageView` (for multi-touch events only) but the problem occurs both ways. Here's the code for drawing:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects];
 int count = [allTouches count];
 if(count==1){//single touch case for drawing line
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:myImageView];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myImageView.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, myImageView.frame.size.width, myImageView.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    lastPoint = currentPoint;
 }
else{//multi touch case
   // handle pinch/zoom
  }
}
```

Here is the image drawn over without zooming:

[image]

And this is the image depicting the problem after zooming-in with the red arrow showing the segment that was already drawn before zooming-in (as shown in previous image). The image is both blurred and displaced:

[image]

It can also be noticed that a part of the line drawn towards the end is unaffected and the phenomenon occurs for lines drawn back in time. I believe the reason for this is that the image size attributes are being lost when I zoom in/out which probably causes the blur and shift, but I'm not sure about that!

**EDIT**- I've uploaded [a short video](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=ivbkn5&s=5) to show what's happening. It's sort of entertaining...

**EDIT 2-** Here's [a sample single-view app](http://cl.ly/3e2E3I1F400k3V1v3F0S) focussing on the problem.

Comment: I think this might have something to do with the contentMode of the view you're drawing in. Try UIViewContentModeRedraw?

Comment: I tried setting it for `myImageView` and `drawImage` (both are `UIImageView`s) but it didn't work :( ...

Comment: @kevboh I've uploaded a video (and added in the answer) which might give you a better idea of the problem...

Comment: I see now. That's very strange—sorry I can't help more :/

Comment: @kevboh no problem man...thnx for trying...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded your project and I found the problem is of autoresizing. The following steps will solve it:

**Step 1.** Comment the line 70:

```
drawImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, labOrderImgView.frame.size.width, labOrderImgView.frame.size.height);
```

in your `touchesMoved` method.

**Step 2.** Add one line of code after drawImage is `alloc`ed (line 90) in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
drawImage.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Then, the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented behavior like this in next way:

1. You should remember all coordinates of your path (MODEL).
2. Draw your path into temporary subview of imageView.
3. When user starts pinch/zoom your image - do nothing, i.e path will be scaled by iOS
4. In the moment when user has finished pinch zooming - redraw your path in correct way using your model.

If you save path as image you get bad looking scaling as result.
Also - **do not draw path straight to image** - draw to some **transparent view and split** them together at the end of editing.

Comment: BTW, I considered your code example - and I would recommend you to implement catching/saving path separately from drawing. This may help you to avoid many troubles. Model-View-Controller pattern.

Comment: Actually, the bad results don't come about while zooming. It's when I draw **after** zooming that this weirdness happens. Do watch the short video in the question to get a better idea.

Comment: Yes I saw video - it is some blurred effect - do not draw path straight to image - draw to some transparent view and split them together at the end of editing.

Comment: Have a question: do you check if frames of drawImage and myImageView are the same : [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, myImageView.frame.size.width, myImageView.frame.size.height)];

Comment: Yeah...in fact, in `touchesBegan`, I ensure that-`drawImage.frame = myImageView.frame`

Comment: Ok...I tried by drawing in `drawImage` and adding it as subview but still the same problem...

Comment: So, last advice (I already said) - separate model from drawing. Do not draw on a fly. But use MODEL (saved paths, scaling parameter...) to refresh your view. Draw into UIView but not into UIImage. Split them after end of editing.

Comment: It might help if you post some code snippet I can compare my code with and try to figure out what's wrong here!

Comment: I tried your way but the problem persists. Saving the points helped me later to give the undo/redo effect, though, so thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are always just drawing to an image context the size of your image view - this of course gets blurry, as you do not adapt to a higher resolution when zoomed in. It would be more sensible to instead create a `UIBezierPath` once and just add a line to it (with `addLineToPoint:`) in the `touchesMoved` method, then draw it in a custom `drawRect` method via `[bezierPath stroke]`. You could also just add a `CAShapeLayer` as a subview of the image view and set its `path` property to the `CGPath` property of the `bezierPath` you created earlier.

See [Drawing bezier curves with my finger in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672646/drawing-bezier-curves-with-my-finger-in-ios) for an example.