# UIView animations on a path not linear

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I animate the movement of a view or image along a curved path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142727/how-can-i-animate-the-movement-of-a-view-or-image-along-a-curved-path)

I have an iOS application that I want to animate a falling leaf (or several). I have my leaf image in an `ImageView` and I've figured out a simple animation from the documentation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0f
                          delay:0
                          options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                          animations:^(void)
                          {
                              leaf1ImageView.frame = CGRectMake(320, 480, leaf1ImageView.frame.size.width,leaf1ImageView.frame.size.height);
                          }
                          completion:NULL];
```

This will make the leaf go from its starting position to the bottom right corner in a straight line. How would I animate this to follow a path or curve like a parabola or sinusoid and maybe even rotate the image or view? Would this be done in the animations block? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with a [CAKeyframeAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) and a [CGPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html). The code looks something like this:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *leafAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
leafAnimation.duration = 10.0;
leafAnimation.path = /* your CGPathRef */;
[leaf1ImageView.layer addAnimation:leafAnimation forKey:@"leafAnimation"];
```

Comment: But if I use this I cannot get the position of UIView while animating them.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for is animating along a Bezier CGPath.  For more details see this question:

[How can I animate the movement of a view or image along a curved path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142727/how-can-i-animate-the-movement-of-a-view-or-image-along-a-curved-path)

Creating bezier paths in code is rather hard though, for easier ways to create a bezier curve to animate along look through the answers to the question here:

[Drawing bezier curves with my finger in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672646/drawing-bezier-curves-with-my-finger-in-ios)

Comment: the linked question is about drawing, but this question is about animation!

Comment: You need to define the path before you can animate on it.  Defining Bezier Paths in code alone is nigh impossible, hence I linked to a useful resource.  You'll note my answer DOES address animation.  I agree though my answer was rather murky, so I added more detail, another link, and clarified why I was adding the drawing link.

Comment: Yes, this is a good reference and is very useful